# I can connect to PostgreSQL server, but encounter "The server does not support SSL connections" error generating migration

Tags: postgresql, deployment, nestjs, typeorm

My sql server is on render.com.

Config for typeorm:

```
export const dataSourceConfig: DataSourceOptions = {
  type: "postgres",
  host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
  port: Number(process.env.DATABASE_PORT || "5432"),
  username: process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
  entities: ["dist/**/*.entity.js"],
  migrations: ["dist/db/migrations/*.js"],
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  },
};
```

If I attempt to set the SSL option to false (as recommended in a similar question), I am unable to establish a connection to the SQL server at all.

This is my list of migration commands:

> "typeorm": "npx typeorm -d dist/db/data-source.js",
> "migration:generate": "npm run typeorm -- migration:generate",
> "migration:run": "npm run typeorm -- migration:run",

Comment: "If I attempt to set the SSL option to false". Show us that code, and that error message.

Comment: I just set ssl: false. On the first attempt, the error is: SSL/TLS required. Then, I encountered: read ECONNRESET.

Comment: The reason for the first error is obvious and expected.  It is the 2nd error, with `ssl: false`, which needs to be investigated in depth. You say the migration fails.  Do normal connections also fail?  Is there any error message in the server log file?  What if you try to connect with `psql` instead of `node` (from the same machine as node is running)?

Comment: When I include the parameter 'rejectUnauthorized: false', the normal connection works properly, and I can also connect via the psql command. Thank you for pointing out the second error to me, I'll look into it more closely.

Comment: This makes it seem like your configuration somehow has migrations trying to connect to a different database server than non-migrations are.  Different host or different port, something like that.